# TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function.(In 'firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)','firebase.initializeApp' is undefined)

Tags: firebase, react-native

When I import firebase on react-native then faces some issues like this.

[image: TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function]

```
import * as firebase  from "firebase";
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "[data_private]",
  authDomain: "[data_private]",
  databaseURL: "https://[data_private].firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "[data_private]",
  storageBucket: "[data_private]",
  messagingSenderId: "[data_private]",
  appId: "[data_private]"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup):

First you need to install `firebase` package:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

Then import it using `firebase/app`:

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and
// must be listed before other Firebase SDKs
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the latest version of the firebase.

You can use`yarn add @react-native-firebase/app` or `npm i @react-native-firebase/app`.

And then import firebase from it.

For reference, you can use [react-native-firebase](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `firebase` package which is for web. You must use native packages like `react-native-firebase`

Answer (score 1):

For me, this solution is working

**Step 1:** Install firebase using npm:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

**Step 2:** Add this line of code in your react native code:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "[private_data]",
    authDomain: "[private_data]",
    projectId: "[private_data]",
    storageBucket: "[private_data]",
    messagingSenderId: "[private_data]",
    appId: "[private_data]",
    measurementId: "[private_data]"
};
const fireApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log(fireApp);
```